# Is it legal to change user agent?

Tags: internet, software

Assume (hypothetically), I'm using jsoup to download certain news website in my public android app. When I don't change user-agent in `jsoup` it redirects me to another website.

Is it legal to change the user agent of my public app, so the user of the app will get the correct news article? Does it matter that the website is scraped a little after downloading it?

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=scraping

Comment: We have many questions "is it legal to do X" when the real question is "if someone doesn't want me to do Y and prevents me from doing Y, and I can get around it by doing X, is it allowed for me to do Y?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Read the ToS of the website

News websites implement such measures because unscrupulous people infringe on the copyright of their articles. Typically, such websites **also** have terms os service that explicitly makes usage of the website contingent on not scraping the website. For example, [the New York Times](https://help.nytimes.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014893428-Terms-of-Service) say:

> 4. PROHIBITED USE OF THE SERVICES
>
> You may not access or use, or attempt to access or use, the Services to take any action that could harm us or a third party. You may not use the Services in violation of applicable laws or in violation of our or any third party’s intellectual property or other proprietary or legal rights. You further agree that you shall not attempt (or encourage or support anyone else's attempt) to circumvent, reverse engineer, decrypt, or otherwise alter or interfere with the Services, or any content thereof, or make any unauthorized use thereof. **Without NYT’s prior written consent, you shall not:**
>
> (i) access any part of the Services, Content, data or information you do not have permission or authorization to access or for which NYT has revoked your access;
>
> (ii) use robots, spiders, scripts, service, **software or any manual or automatic device, tool, or process designed to data mine or scrape the Content, data or information from the Services, or otherwise access or collect the Content, data or information from the Services using automated means;**

Violating the Terms of Service means, you are in breach of contract and got no license to access any of the data. This allows claims starting with breach of contract and going up to intruding into the servers and violating various computer crime laws. However, do note that having a possible charge does not mean that it will result in a  trial or even conviction.

Comment: So, it's better that the user opens the website in the browser, save it to the secondary storage and then open in my app? Actually I don't scrape the website, I only download it via Jsoup and then scrape it a little and display it in my app. So, the website refuses the jsoup user agent. So I shouldn't change the user agent globally, for every webpage I use jsoup to download?

Comment: That is answering the question if scraping websites is legal, which might be the better question, but is not really what was asked :-).

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes. The website refuses jsoup user-agent. It's not being scraped yet. I could then display the website as is, without scraping (with ads and unrelated stuff)

Comment: @xralf displaying the page as is is displaying the page as the site owner wants it to be seen - then your app is a browser.

Comment: @Trish So, it's only legal, that the user will save the website to harddrive via browser and then he can read it in any way he wants? (e.g. pure html, RSS reader etc.)

Comment: @xralf let me repeat that for you: Read the relevant Terms of Service. For Convenience, have those of the NYT, which explicitly address your complete use case and its derivative suggestions. Many other news sites copy the terms of service of the NYT in spirit or even verbatim.

Comment: OK. If I understand it well, the user can store the webpage to his/her harddrive via a browser and then use whatever app (e.g. RSS reader) to read html page and the whatever app (e.g. RSS reader) isn't responsible for webpage it processes. It just processes html.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to prove a negative (there is no comprehensive list of things that are legal). However a specific user agent name is not mandated by any law, so there can hardly be a law against changing it [*] (think of it this way, instead of using jsoup you could write your own crawler/parser - there is no government agency that would knock at your door and ask you to use a specific name for your software).

Here in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) there is a law against circumventing effective protective measures to get access to a computer system, but it is doubtful that a website would be considered a computer system in the meaning of the law, and relying on the user agent would not be effective protective measures.

A site might try to ban scraping via their terms of service, but that would not always be enforceable, and would not depend on your user agent name. I still would not recommend to rely on data that a company does not want you to scrape, because even without legal measures they have ways to make this infeasible as a business model (and there might be legal issue such as copyright that still apply).

But as far as UA names go, knock yourself out.

[*] If it is a configurable property of your software. The software itself might have terms of service that prevent you from changing its properties, but I take it this is not what you are asking about.

Comment: So, my app may process any html that the user inputs in it, and my app is not allowed to download some websites that have it disabled in their ToS? So it is more safe for the developer to download no websites (I have a form where the user puts a link) or restrict (filter) only the websites with positive ToS and nothing more? Or create both functionalities, first form for browsing any html files in the user file system and second functionality for inputing links to websites with positive ToS? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I would think that checking the user agent is an effective protective measure. Not perfect, it can be circumvented, but most people wouldn't know how to do that, so it is effective. Stronger protection methods alway have the risk that legitimate uses may be prevented accidentally, so you want legal protection for less strong technical protection.